# It doesn't print the names on screen with fetch call

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have to call the data from the given URL with fetch call. It should print the name of academy in  and student names in  on screen but when I click the button nothing happens. I know maybe its a huge code and it takes time but I would be grateful if someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function printStudents(responseStudents) {
        let h1Element = $(`<h1></h1>`).text(`${responseStudents.academy}`);
        let uList = $(`<ul></ul>`);

        $("body").append(h1Element, uList);
        for (i = 0; i < responseStudents.length; i++) {
            uList.append(`<li> ${responseStudents.students[i]}</li>`);
        }
    }

    $("#button").click(function () {
        
            fetch ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drakso/AJS2019/master/Class1/students.json")
            .then (function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then (function (data) {
                //let responseStudents = JSON.parse(response);
                //printStudents(responseStudents);
                console.log(data)
                
            },).catch (function (error) {
                alert("USer not found");
            })
        })
})
```

Comment: Code should work, maybe you missed to add `id` for your DOM element?

Comment: Are you seeing any error in browser console ? I am able to fetch the data and console log them.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur i don't have any errors, and yes they come up in console log but i need them on the browser, not in console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to access `length` property of `response` (which I passed here as `data`) object instead of the `students` array so your loop was not running.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function printStudents(data) {
    let h1Element = $(`<h1></h1>`).text(`${data.academy}`);
    let uList = $(`<ul></ul>`);
    let responseStudents = data.students;
    $("body").append(h1Element, uList);
    for (i = 0; i < responseStudents.length; i++) {
        uList.append(`<li> ${responseStudents[i]}</li>`);
    }
}

$("#button").click(function () {
    
        fetch ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drakso/AJS2019/master/Class1/students.json")
        .then (function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then (function (data) {
            printStudents(data);
            
        },).catch (function (error) {
            alert("USer not found");
        })
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id = 'button'>Click me</button>
```